# Type Checking in Monaco Editor

Tags: monaco-editor

Is it possible to enable type checking in Monaco editor? For example I have the following configuration for my editor:

```js
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    noSemanticValidation: false,
    noSyntaxValidation: false
});

monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2016,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true,
    noLib: true
});

//Passed into monaco.editor.create(...)
let editorOptions = {
  value: '',
  language: 'javascript',
  scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
  theme: "vs-dark",
  minimap: {
    enabled: false
  },
  automaticLayout: true,
  wordWrap: "on"
}
```

Additionally, I have the following code which adds a custom class and method to the editor environment:

```js
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib([
    'declare class Foo {}',
    'declare function bar(foo: Foo)'
].join('\n'), 'filename/example.d.ts');
```

However, in Monaco, I can still type the following code `bar("str")`, and the editor will not throw an error even though `"str"` is not of type `Foo`. Is it possible to turn on static type checking in Monaco?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with the following, it seems the set overwrites any existing config so I'm spreading in the current config to extend it

```js
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    ...monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.getDiagnosticsOptions(),
    noSemanticValidation: false,
    noSuggestionDiagnostics: false,
    noSyntaxValidation: false
});


monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    ...monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.getCompilerOptions(),
    checkJs: true // need this
});
```